# Textarea Box (Button that Adds Text in HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to display HTML inside a textarea box for a link. I am able to get it working perfectly except I want it to display `<a href="https://youtube.com">Link</a>` instead of Code for Link in HTML.

How can you display text for HTML this way? Below shows two examples. The one on top works.

HTML that Displays "Code for Link in HTML"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value += "Code for Link in HTML"
}
</script>
</html>
```

HTML that should display `<a href="https://youtube.com">Link</a>` but is not...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value += "<a href="https://youtube.com">Link</a>"
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your example didn't work because you didn't escape your inner quotes. Do this by putting a backslash on your inner quotes inside the quote:

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea").value += "<a href=\"https://youtube.com\">Link</a>"
```

Secondly, you can't display HTML inside a textarea. You will need a contenteditable div to satisfy your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `addEventListener` method to attach an event to the button.
And also use [`escaping a character`](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping) to avoid problems with `js interpreter`: "<a href=\"https:\/\/youtube.com\">Link<\/a>"

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<button id="btn" type="button">Add Link</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener(
'click', myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value += 
  "<a href=\"https:\/\/youtube.com\">Link<\/a>"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve by **backtick `` operator**. So use backtick **`** instead of double quotes **"** to set value of textarea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value += `<a href="https://youtube.com">Link</a>`
}
</script>
</html>
```